# knitr - exclude chunks from `purl(...)`?

Tags: r, knitr

When I purl/tangle a document to extract the R chunks into a script, is there any way to:

- exclude an arbitrary chunk (by name say)?
- if not, exclude a chunk if `eval=F` (or perhaps I can define a chunk hook/option `include=F`)?

---

For example, suppose I have the following Rmd:

````
```{r setup, echo=F}
library(MASS)
```
First, we perform the setup (assume for some reason I need to evaluate `setup`
silently before I wish to display the chunk to the user, hence the repetition)
```{r setup, eval=F}
```

Here's the function I've been explaining:
```{r function}
plus <- function (a, b) a + b
```

And here's an example of its use:
```{r example}
plus(1, 2)
```
````

The tangled script looks like this:

```
## @knitr setup, echo=F
library(MASS)   

## @knitr setup, eval=F
library(MASS)

## @knitr function
plus <- function (a, b) a + b

## @knitr example
plus(1, 2)
```

I have the idea that since I *didn't* want particular chunks to be evaluated, they at the very least should not appear in the output (in the example above, the second `setup` chunk).

Additionally it would be nice for me to mark some chunks as "invisible" with respect to the tangled output. I don't want the `example` chunk in my output script (it was nice in the Rmd for purposes of documentation, but I want to be able to tangle the Rmd and then just `source('myfile.r')` if I wish to use the `plus` function, without having to worry about these extra examples executing. Currently I tangle the Rmd and then *manually* edit out the chunks I don't want out of the script, which seems against the principle of just writing the one Rmd which will provide both documentation and script without extra effort.)

Comment: Note - marking a chunk with `include=F` will remove it from the `purl`'d output, but *also* from the Rmd (in the version of knitr from github that is; feature doesn't seem present on my computer's version 1.2), so this is not ideal for my `example` block (where I want it *included* in the Rmd and removed from the purl'd output)

Comment: there is certainly a lot of room for improvement of `purl()`, which is less frequently used, hence less well developed

Comment: Is there no way to just extract r chunks from an Rmd?

Comment: @KLDavenport to extract all R chunks from an Rmd into an R script, you use `purl`. It extracts all of the chunks, and I'm interested in extracting just some of them (or even extracting particular chunks to particular output files).

Comment: I couldn't get a simple export of all chunks to work but I'll look over the documentation again. Bummer that you can set config per chunk for export in your case.

Comment: @Yihui, not sure if my answer below is general enough for inclusion in knitr but I couldn't find any reason _not_ to expand params when processing tangle blocks...

Comment: As of 2023, `include=F` does not remove from `purl` output, it only removes it from `knit` output

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since [`knitr`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) 1.3, there is a new chunk option `purl = TRUE/FALSE` that allows one to include/exclude certain code chunks for `purl()`.

````
```{r test, purl=FALSE}
library(MASS)
```
````

Answer (score 7):

The tangle processing block doesn't currently expand params, but we can make it do so...

```
# See `?trace` documentation for details.
bdy <- as.list( body( knitr:::process_tangle.block ) )
trace.at <- which( grepl(".*opts_chunk\\$merge.*",
                         as.list( body( knitr:::process_tangle.block ) ) ) )
tracer <- quote({
  # Code borrowed from normal chunk procesing.
  af = opts_knit$get('eval.after'); al = opts_knit$get('aliases')
  if (!is.null(al) && !is.null(af)) af = c(af, names(al[af %in% al]))
  for (o in setdiff(names(params), af)) params[o] = list(eval_lang(params[[o]]))
  # Omit this if using lastest knitr source from github.
  if( isFALSE( params$include ) ) {
    tmp <- knit_code$get();
    tmp[[params$label]] <- "";
    knit_code$restore(tmp)
  }
})

trace( knitr:::process_tangle.block, tracer=tracer, at=trace.at, print=FALSE )
```

Then purl() exclusion can be controlled using option arguments...

`````
```{r setup, echo=TRUE, results='hide'}
library(MASS)
````

First, we perform the setup (assume for some reason I need to evaluate `setup`
silently before I wish to display the chunk to the user, hence the repetition)
```{r setup2, ref.label="setup", echo=FALSE, results='markup'}
```

Here's the function I've been explaining:
```{r function}
plus <- function (a, b) a + b
```

And here's an example of its use:
```{r example, eval=!opts_knit$get("tangle") }
plus(1, 2)
```

And here's another example of its use:
```{r example2, include=!opts_knit$get("tangle") }
plus(3, 3)
```
`````

Comment: However, this still does not allow me to *exclude* chunks that I choose (For example. in the example I gave in the question, I want to exclude the 'example' chunk)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee @Thell thanks for the exploration; I think I will have add a separate chunk option to allow certain chunks to be excluded from `purl()`; let me think more about this.

Comment: @Yihui That'd be great!  If it doesn't _hurt_ anything then expanding the params would be nice as hook options could be programmatically set as well, to emit different results...

Comment: @Thell I completely agree with you. The only problem is when the params uses objects from the code chunks, and then `purl()` will require the execution of code chunks. Perhaps we literate programming people are all wrong from the very beginning -- literate programming should not be either `weave` or `tangle`, but `weave[tangle]` (optionally `tangle` within the `weave` process).

Answer (score 3):

Although this is more a trick than a solution, you can still modify the script resulting from purl with some regular expressions.

For example with the following function (maybe there is a simpler solution for the regex) :

```
dropchunks <- function(scriptname, what.to.drop){
    script <- readLines(scriptname)
    script <- do.call(paste, list(script, collapse = "\n") )
    subpattern = paste0("(", do.call(paste, list(what.to.drop, collapse="|")), ")")
    mainpattern <- paste('(?s)## @knitr ((?!## @knitr).)*?', subpattern, '.*?((?=## @knitr)|$)', sep="")
    script <- gsub(pattern = mainpattern, replacement = "", x = script, perl=TRUE)
    writeLines(text = script, con= scriptname)
}
```

You can then do this to remove all code chunk containing eval=F :

```
library(knitr)
purl("test.Rmd")
dropchunks("test.R", "eval=F")
```

You can do this to remove the chunk named "function" or "example" (and in fact it will remove any chunk that contains these words somewhere but this could be changed by changing the regex):

```
purl("test.Rmd")
dropchunks("test.R", c("function", "example"))
```

Comment: I like the idea! Since knitr doesn't complain about unknown args in the chunk a simple ```{r test, purl=F} could be set as a default "what.to.drop".