# render new conditional .Rmd from existing .Rmd

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am building a shiny app that creates an .Rmd report based on user inputs. I am able to `render()` the .Rmd to .html, etc. and selectively exclude code chunks from the output using `echo=FALSE`, and preventing them from running with `eval=FALSE`.

What I'd like to do is remake a new .Rmd from the existing one and select which chunks are written to it based on the same conditional logic. In other words, `render()` the .Rmd to a new .Rmd instead of another file type. The reason for this is because I'd like to offer the user an .Rmd file that represents the current user session, and that can be rerun in RStudio for reproducibility.

This is what I'd like to do:

## EXAMPLE

Existing .Rmd

````
---
title: User Session `r Sys.Date()`
output: html_document
author: "Johnny Johnson"
---

```{r, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
con1 <- input$userCharInput1 != ""
```

This text will render regardless of what the user does.

```{asis, echo = con1}
This text will only render if con1 is TRUE.
```

```{r, echo = con1, eval = con1}
out1 <- someFun(input$userCharInput1)
out1
```

```{r}
out2 <- sum(c(10, 20))
out2
```
````

Output .Rmd

````
---
title: User Session `r Sys.Date()`
output: html_document
author: "Johnny Johnson"
---

This text will render regardless of what the user does.

```{r}
out2 <- sum(c(10, 20))
out2
```
````

What is the best strategy for this? If there is no straightforward way with existing `knitr` or `rmarkdown` functionality, I suppose it's possible to write the .Rmd in server.R as the session progresses, but this seems tedious. Any input will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Should the new file contain only chunks where `eval` *and* `echo` are `TRUE`, or those with `eval = TRUE` (regardless of `echo`) or …? What about text between chunks, should everything be part of the new file?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the chunk parameter is, but I'd like chunks to conditionally not appear in the new .Rmd. Ideally, I would engineer a custom param to do this. Text between code chunks is all organized in `{asis, ...}` chunks, so a single param that does this would work throughout the document.

Comment: Not an answer because I'm not done (and don't have the time) … `purl` can be used to [extract code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20288145/2706569) but this is not helpful for Rmd --> Rmd. I think it's necessary to parse the file just like `knitr` does, something along the lines of `pat_md();lines <- readLines(con = "test.Rmd");res <- knitr:::split_file(lines)` but I'm not sure how to proceed with `res`. Alternatively, a chunk hook could be used that constructs a new Rmd file based on `opts_current$get("code")` and the current options. Maybe this helps you getting started.

Comment: Looking into hooks, I realized that rendering to `md_document()` works almost perfectly for me, but the closest formatting is `markdown_github`, where code chunk are formatted ` ``` r... ``` `. There must be a way to customize an output hook like `md_document()` to put `{}` around the `r`, because I think that's exactly what I want. Then the user can just run all chunks on RStudio to reproduce the results of the session.

Comment: Well, I think I understand what you're doing. But this basically gives you the *code* of the chunks, formatted as code using markdown. What you loose are the chunk options, right? I've been thinking about this for a while now. IMHO the best solution is to `knit` the document, use a chunk hook to capture the labels of all active chunks and use the regual expressions in `all_patterns$md` to extract the chunks. Could you add a sample Rmd file to the question?

Comment: For my purposes, I actually don't need the chunk options -- all I want is an executable .Rmd that will not need more knitting. I'll provide a sample later today. Thanks for your help thus far, @user2706569.

Comment: Figured out a hacky way to do this with regex substitutions. In the `downloadHandler()` of  `server.R`, I dropped in `out <- render('userReport.Rmd', md_document(variant="markdown_github"))` and `writeLines(gsub('``` r', '```{r}', readLines(out)), 'userReport2.Rmd')`, then set `out <- 'userReport2.Rmd'`. Simple as that. This does not, however, save any of the chunk options in the output .Rmd.

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution. So are you satisfied with your current workaround or would you prefer something that preserves chunk options?

Comment: I think if you have a solution that preserves the options, it would be good to disseminate to the community as an answer. But I am satisfied with my easy solution thus far.

Comment: Ok. I think I have an idea and I will try to turn it into an answer in the next days.