# Exclude comment lines with chunk title and options with purl

Tags: r, knitr

When I `purl()` a .Rnw or .Rmd file, the resulting .R file has a commented line for each chunk that includes the chunk title and options for that particular chunk. I would like to distribute the .R file for a lecture, and think the extra lines, particularly the chunk options, are distracting for students. For example the chunk:

```
<<my_chunk, eval=FALSE>>=
x <- 1 + 2
@
```

ends up looking like:

```
## ----my_chunk, eval=FALSE------------------------------------------------
x <- 1 + 2
```

in the `purl`ed file. I would like to completely eliminate the commented line, or at the very least, the chunk options (i.e., `eval=FALSE`). What is the most straightforward way to do that? I did not have this issue with a previous version of `knitr`.

Comment: maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431100/knitr-exclude-chunks-from-purl/17157450#17157450

Comment: Hmm I was hoping for a knitr option or something, but that works, too.